# How to spy on functions outside a component?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

```
// ./index.js
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
    method () {
        console.log('method()');
    }

    do () {
        this.method();
        func();
    }

    render () {
        return null;
    }
}

export function func () {
    console.log('func()');
}

// ./index.test.js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import * as Test from './index';

describe('<Test>', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Test.default/>),
          method_spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), 'method'),
          func_spy = jest.spyOn(Test, 'func');

    test('func()', () => {
        component.instance().do();
        expect(method_spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // passed
        expect(func_spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // failed
    });
});
```

I want to spy on function outside a component, but It doesn't work well.

I've got a message like `Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.`

And I don't want to use mock() method instead of spyOn() in the situation.

Is there way to fix it? Thaks you for reading. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because this line:

```js
const func_spy = jest.spyOn(Test, 'func');
```

...is creating a spy on the *module export* for `func`...

...but `Test.do` doesn't call the *module export* for `func`, it calls `func` directly.

---

There are two options to fix it.

One is to move `func` into its own module.

Then the *module export* for it will be imported into `index.js` and called within `Test.do`...

...and when the *module export* for `func` is wrapped in a spy the spy will get called by `Test.do`.

---

The other option is to note that ["ES6 modules support cyclic dependencies automatically"](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_cyclic-dependencies-in-ecmascript-6) so a module can be imported into itself.

If the module is imported into itself then `Test.do` can call the *module export* for `func`:

```js
import { Component } from 'react';
import * as index from './index';  // <= import the module into itself

export default class Test extends Component {
  method() {
    console.log('method()');
  }

  do() {
    this.method();
    index.func();  // <= use the module
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export function func() {
  console.log('func()');
}
```

...and the spy on the *module export* for `func` will be called as expected:

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import * as Test from './index';

describe('<Test>', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Test.default />),
    method_spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), 'method'),
    func_spy = jest.spyOn(Test, 'func');

  test('func()', () => {
    component.instance().do();
    expect(method_spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!
    expect(func_spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!
  });
});
```

Comment: You're right! And I went over that part of the `Jest`'s source code. I have realized It happened because I did not know how `spyOn()` works. Thanks.